# Pyspark join two tables based on distance

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables `store` and `weather_station`. to find the closes **weather station** from a particular **store** and create a new table with this details I am using following code.

```
def closest(weather_station, store):
    return min(weather_station, key=lambda p: distance(store['lat'], store['lon'], p['lat'], p['lon']))

for store in store_details:
    print store
    print closest(weather_station_details, store)
```

it works fine without any issue. if I run with this sample data, I get the correct result.

```
weather_station_details=[
    {'date': '2018-03-06T13:00:00.000Z', 'station_cd': 'CYGK', 'station_nm': 'Kingston', 'lat': 44.22587, 'lon': -76.5966},
    {'date': '2018-03-06T13:00:00.000Z', 'station_cd': 'CXOA', 'station_nm': 'OTTAWA CDA RCS', 'lat': 45.383333, 'lon': -75.716667},
    {'date': '2018-03-06T13:00:00.000Z', 'station_cd': 'CYUL', 'station_nm': 'Montreal/Trudeau International', 'lat': 45.47046, 'lon': -73.74093},
    {'date': '2018-03-06T13:00:00.000Z', 'station_cd': 'CYYC', 'station_nm': 'Calgary International', 'lat': 51.12262, 'lon': -114.01335},
    {'date': '2018-03-06T12:00:00.000Z', 'station_cd': 'CPEA', 'station_nm': 'EDGERTON AGCM', 'lat': 52.783333, 'lon': -110.433333},
    {'date': '2018-03-06T12:00:00.000Z', 'station_cd': 'CPEH', 'station_nm': 'ENCHANT AGDM', 'lat': 50.183333, 'lon': -112.433333},
    {'date': '2018-03-06T12:00:00.000Z', 'station_cd': 'CPGE', 'station_nm': 'GILT EDGE NORTH AGCM', 'lat': 53.066667, 'lon': -110.616667},
    {'date': '2018-03-06T12:00:00.000Z', 'station_cd': 'CPHU', 'station_nm': 'HUGHENDEN AGCM AB', 'lat': 52.583333, 'lon': -110.783333},
    {'date': '2018-03-06T12:00:00.000Z', 'station_cd': 'CPIR', 'station_nm': 'IRON SPRINGS AGDM', 'lat': 49.9, 'lon': -112.733333},
]

store_details=[
    {'lon': -113.99361, 'store_num': 'A111', 'lat': 51.201838},
    {'lon': -73.792339, 'store_num': 'A222', 'lat': 45.53343},
    {'lon': -75.699475, 'store_num': 'A333', 'lat': 45.475785},
    {'lon': -76.564509, 'store_num': 'A444', 'lat': 44.244361},
]
```

However, as data is huge and to get performance I am trying to use `pyspark`. However I am stuck. I can't pass the one data frame as a argument to function or can't make it global.

is there anyway I can achieve this in pyspark?

Comment: Could you give some more detail about the distance function that you use. Where does it come from? Or how did you code it?

Comment: @plalanne i have got it from internet. however it works.

Comment: I would need it to give you a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

There are are least a couple of ways to do this. I'm providing only outlines here.

One approach:

1. Define a UDF `distance` to calculate the distance between an arbitrary store and weather station pair.
2. Perform a cartesian join of your `stores` dataframe with your `weather_stations` dataframe. If one of these dataframes is small (a few MB), you could force it to be a broadcast join. (Warning: this will result in a dataframe with a size of M x N, where M and N are the size of the two original dataframes. This could easily blow up your available storage.)
3. Use your UDF to calculate the distance between each store / station pair.
4. Either group by store or use a window function partitioned by store to select the weather station with minimum distance.

Another approach:

1. Define a UDF `min_distance` that takes a store and finds the weather station with the minimum distance. Again, if the list of weather stations is reasonably small, then it would be appropriate to broadcast the weather stations data structure to speed up this step.
2. Apply this UDF to your `stores` dataframe.